# How to check if a string is in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I basically need a function to check whether a string's characters (each character) is in an array.

My code isn't working so far, but here it is anyway,

```
$allowedChars = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," ","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"," ","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"," ","@",".","-","_","+"," ");

$input = "Test";
$input = str_split($input);

if (in_array($input,$allowedChars)) {echo "Yep, found.";}else {echo "Sigh, not found...";}
```

I want it to say 'Yep, found.' if one of the letters in $input is found in `$allowedChars`.  Simple enough, right?  Well, that doesn't work, and I haven't found a function that will search a string's individual characters for a value in an array.

By the way, I want it to be just those array's values, I'm not looking for fancy html_strip_entities or whatever it is, I want to use that exact array for the allowed characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really should look into regex and the preg_match function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

But, this should make your specific request work:

```
$allowedChars = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"," ","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"," ","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"," ","@",".","-","_","+"," ");
$input = "Test";
$input = str_split($input);
$message = "Sigh, not found...";
foreach($input as $letter) {
    if (in_array($letter, $allowedChars)) {
        $message = "Yep, found.";
        break;
    }
}
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with regular expressions at all? It's sort of the more accepted way of doing what you're trying to do, unless I'm missing something here.

Take a look at preg_match(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

To address your example, here's some sample code (**UPDATED TO ADDRESS ISSUES IN COMMENTS**):

```
$subject = "Hello, this is a string";
$pattern = '/[a-zA-Z0-9 @._+-]*/'; // include all the symbols you want to match here

if (preg_match($pattern, $subject))
    echo "Yep, matches";
else
    echo "Doesn't match :(";
```

A little explanation of the regex: the '^' matches the beginning of the string, the '[a-zA-Z0-9 @._+-]' part means "any character in this set", the '*' after it means "zero or more of the last thing", and finally the '$' at the end matches the end of the string.

Comment: Ah, thank you, but when I run that it says that the - before the underscore gives it an error :( why is that?  

No I am not familiar with RegEx :P, well I have heard of it but I can't do it worth anything :P

Comment: This is not what he want. See "if one of the letters in $input is found in". To fix that, remove '^' and '$'.

Comment: Hmm, I've done that but it still gives me this error:

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '-' in /home/jaxo/web/tests/test.php on line (line with preg_match statement)

Comment: how bout using a posix character class match like [:graph:] and from the looks of it [:blank:] or [:space:] for all of them see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_character_classes)

Comment: Right, sorry about that; I just wrote it without thinking too much about the expression. Yes, the '-' is invalid in a character class unless it comes at the beginning or the end (I've moved it to the end in the answer). Sorry for the trouble. :\

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat different approach:

```
$allowedChars = array("a","b","c","d","e");
$char_buff = explode('', "Test");
$foundTheseOnes = array_intersect($char_buff, $allowedChars);
if(!empty($foundTheseOnes)) {
    echo 'Yep, something was found. Let\'s find out what: <br />';
    print_r($foundTheseOnes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Validating the characters in a string is most appropriately done with string functions.
`preg_match()` is the most direct/elegant method for this task.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9458f86de368f837506245241dd3b444375c6175))

```
$input="Test Test Test Test";
if(preg_match('/^[\w +.@_-]*$/',$input)){
    echo "Input string does not contain any disallowed characters";
}else{
    echo "Input contains one or more disallowed characters";
}
// output: Yes, input contains only allowed characters
```

Pattern Explanation:

```
/          # start pattern
^          # start matching from start of string
[\w +.@-]  # match: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, underscore, space, plus, dot, atsign, hyphen
*          # zero or more occurrences
$          # match until end of string
/          # end pattern
```

Significant points:

- The `^` and `$` anchors are crucial to ensure that the entire string is validated versus just a substring of the string.
- The `\w` (a.k.a. "any word character" -> a [shorthand character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)) is the easy way to write: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- The `.` [dot character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) loses its "match anything (almost)" meaning and becomes literal when it is written inside of a character class.  No escaping slash is necessary.
- The hyphen inside of a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) can be written without an escaping slash (`\-`) so long as the it is positioned at the start or end of the character class.  If the hyphen is not at the start/end and it is not escaped, it will create a range of characters between the characters on either side of it.
  Like it or not, `[.-z]` will not match a hyphen symbol because it does not exist "between" the dot character and the lowercase letter z on the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).
- The `*` that follows the character class is the "[quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)".  The asterisk means "0 or more" of the preceding character class.  In this case, this means that `preg_match()` will allow an empty string.  If you want to deny an empty string, you can use `+` which means "1 or more" of the preceding character class.  Finally, you can be far more specific about string length by using a number or numbers in a curly bracketed expression.

  - `{8}` would mean the string must be exactly 8 characters long.
  - `{4,}` would mean the string must be at least 4 characters long.
  - `{,10}` would mean the string length must be between 0 and 10.
  - `{5,9}` would mean the string length must be between 5 and 9 characters.

---

All of that advice aside, if you absolutely must use your array of characters AND you wanted to use a loop to check individual characters against your validation array (and I certainly don't recommend it), then the goal should be to reduce the number of array elements involved so as to reduce total iterations.

- Your `$allowedChars` array has multiple elements that contain the space character, but only one is necessary.  You should prepare the array using `array_unique()` or a similar technique.
- `str_split($input)` will run the chance of generating an array with duplicate elements.  For example, if `$input="Test Test Test Test";` then the resultant array from `str_split()` will have 19 elements, 14 of which will require redundant validation checks.
- You could probably eliminate redundancies from `str_split()` by calling `count_chars($input,3)` and feeding that to `str_split()` or alternatively you could call `str_split()` then `array_unique()` before performing the iterative process.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I asked this question a little over 7 years ago!  I hope it helps somebody in the future, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's all I was going for.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're just validating a string, see `preg_match()` and other PCRE functions for handling this instead.

Alternatively, you can use `strcspn()` to do...

```
$check = "abcde.... '; // fill in the rest of the characters
$test = "Test";
echo ((strcspn($test, $check) === strlen($test)) ? "Sigh, not found..." : 'Yep, found.');
```